# Spotify for Windows app is not downloading songs for offline mode

Tags: windows-10, download, music, spotify

So, lately, I decided I want to have some Spotify playlists in offline mode in Spotify for Windows. It successfully downloaded one song, and now all the others just have that little 'syncing' icon. It has been days since I started this.

This is a Windows 10 Lenovo gaming laptop. I have restarted my computer several times. I have restarted the download, but the status doesn't change, and only certain songs in the playlist show the icon. It's like it's completely frozen, but I can still listen to music and everything else.

My internet download speed is 126Mbps and I have about 730GB free space on my hard drive.

How can I make my songs download?

Comment: What happens when you reboot your system and restart the offline download process? Is this with a browser or a standalone app?

Comment: @Enigma It's the app, and I have restarted my computer several times. I have restarted the download, but the status doesn't change, and only certain songs in the playlist show the icon. It's like it's completely frozen, but I can still listen to music and everything else.

Comment: Got another system to try it on? Maybe a reinstall of the app would help.

Comment: @Enigma I'll try reinstalling it and see if that fixes it.